# 'Relation does not exist' error after transferring to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I have transfered my project from MySQL to PostgreSQL and tried to drop the column as result of previous issue, because after I removed the problematic column from models.py and saved. error didn't even disappear. [Integer error transferring from MySQL to PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41193433/integer-error-transferring-from-mysql-to-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment69587617_41193433)

Tried both with and without quotes.

```
ALTER TABLE "UserProfile" DROP COLUMN how_many_new_notifications;
```

Or:

```
ALTER TABLE UserProfile DROP COLUMN how_many_new_notifications;
```

Getting the following:

```
ERROR:  relation "UserProfile" does not exist
```

Here's a model, if helps:

```
 class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    how_many_new_notifications = models.IntegerField(null=True,default=0)
User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

I supposed it might have something to do with mixed-case but I have found no solution through all similar questions.

Comment: Try without the double quotes.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Oh, yes, tried both. It's kind of solution I found and tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Postgresql is a case aware database but django is smart enough to know that. It converts all field and it generally converts the model name to a  lower case table name. However the real problem here is that your model name will be prefixed by the app name. generally django table names are like:

```
<appname>_<modelname>
```

You can find out what exactly it is by:

```py
from myapp.models import UserProfile
print (UserProfile._meta.db_table)
```

Obviously this needs to be typed into the django shell, which is invoked by `./manage.py shell` the result of this print statement is what you should use in your query.

Comment: I can't exactly get, what is right now. My app is named 'blog' so I tried 'blog_UserProfile' but it 'doesn't exits'

Comment: why don't you just print UserProfile._meta.db_table as suggested?

Comment: "ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented" plus I don't really understand the syntax. First is clear, but but what is _meta here for?

Comment: well, what I got in shell is 'blog_userprofile'  exactly what I have tried

Comment: the same error ' relation "blog_userprofile" does not exist'

Comment: please, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202674/postgresql-models-py-is-not-transformed-into-database-scheme

Comment: Now it sounds like your migration hasn't run. Looking at your new question.

Answer (score 0):

- **Client**: [DataGrip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53551360/5279996)
- **Database engine**: PostgreSQL

---

For me this worked **opening a new console**, because apparently from the IDE cache it was not recognizing the table I had created.

[Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53551360/5279996) to operate with the tables of a database:

1. Database (Left side panel of the IDE) >
2. Double Click on PostgreSQL - @localhost >
3. Double Click on the name of the database >
4. Right click on public schema >
5. New > Console

GL