# Switching PostgreSQL database or Schema in DataGrip JetBrains

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, ide, datagrip

Does anybody know how to switch between PostgreSQL databases or schemas in [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)  (The Database IDE from JetBrains) in the console?

i can do that in Mysql by using:

```
Use my_database;
```

I tried using the [Psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) methods like

> \connect

or

> \c

but nothing works.

And could not find anyting in [DataGrip Help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/getting-started-with-datagrip.html).

Comment: DId you get solution with your problem? I get in the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you speaking about the code, use `SET search_path TO my_schema, public;`

If you speaking about the tool, DataGrip, use switcher:

[image]

Comment: Yeah i meant the code,  `SET search_path TO my_schema, public;` wont switch databases, in  it shows that Database Console down it shows that: **sql> SET SEARCH_PATH TO MY_DATABASE, public**
But the code console above still use the same database i mean if i tried to query another database i still get the error :        
_cross-database references are not implemented_

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot with that error in DataGrip?

Comment: don't have a screenshot I can share, but I can confirm that in a console in datagrip the search path command completes without error, but also without changing the context that the session is connected to

Comment: Do you see the set search_path statement in the Servics window?

Answer (score 2):

- **Client**: [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)
- **Database engine**: PostgreSQL

---

To change the use of a database, you can do it by:

- From the Terminal (IDE or SO) with psql
- Through UI with pgAdmin4 (Query Tool) or IDE

### Change the database through UI with the IDE

1. **You can delete the disused consoles** as follows:

   1. Files (*Right side panel of the IDE*) >
   2. Scratches and Consoles >
   3. Database Consoles >
   4. Select the directory PostgreSQL - @localhost (*Name of Project Data Source*) >
   5. Delete disused consoles with right click and delete.
2. **Select a database** to perform sql queries:

   1. Database (*Left side panel of the IDE*) >
   2. Double Click on PostgreSQL - @localhost >
   3. Double Click on the name of the database >
   4. Right click on `public schema` >
   5. New >
   6. Console

In this way in the directory *Files> Scratches and Consoles > Database Consoles > PostgreSQL - @localhost*, a new console positioned in said database was added.

3. Finally, you can **operate with DDL** (create, alter, drop) **or DML** (insert, update, delete, select).

   `CREATE TABLE test_2 (test int);`
   `TABLE test_2;`

Quick tip: With the cursor positioned within the source code and **ctrl+enter** the sql queries are executed in the IDE.

GL